# Access denied in OPC UA .NET Certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, opc

I have recently moved a .net app to a new server and when it tries to connect to the OPC server I got an exception for the application certificate on the following line:

`bool haveAppCertificate = application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 0).Result;`

here is the stack trace of the exception:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Access is
> denied.) --->
> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException:
> Access is denied. at
> Internal.Cryptography.Pal.StorePal.FromSystemStore(String storeName,
> StoreLocation storeLocation, OpenFlags openFlags) at
> System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store.Open(OpenFlags
> flags) at Opc.Ua.X509CertificateStore.Add(X509Certificate2
> certificate, String password) at
> Opc.Ua.X509Utils.AddToStore(X509Certificate2 certificate, String
> storeType, String storePath, String password) at
> Opc.Ua.Configuration.ApplicationInstance.CreateApplicationInstanceCertificate(ApplicationConfiguration
> configuration, UInt16 keySize, UInt16 lifeTimeInMonths) at
> Opc.Ua.Configuration.ApplicationInstance.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(Boolean
> silent, UInt16 minimumKeySize, UInt16 lifeTimeInMonths) --- End of
> inner exception stack trace ---

I have tried to delete and recreate the certificate and check if the publishing folder has admin access.

this is the Nuget package for OPC connection: OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua.Client v1.4.368.58

Update: The code is running on IIS. I'm using my PC to publish the project into a shared folder of a local server. When I run the code in Visual Studio, I can connect to the OPC server application which is installed on my local server, but when it is in publish mode, on IIS, I get the exception for the certificate.

Comment: Are you running from Visual Studio?  VS you are not running As Admin unless you right click VS Shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Outside VS code executable will automatically Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng the code is on the IIS. I have updated my question and add more details.

Comment: IIS will not accept a TLS 1.3 certificate.  A certificate has an encryption mode and some encryption modes will work with TLS 1.2, some will work with TLS 1.3, and others with both 1.2 and 1.3.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: @jdweng Maybe it is not about TLS, I have added TLS 1.2 and 1.3 to my Windows 2019 server registry but nothing has changed. My former server was a Windows 2016 server and I got no exceptions in connections.

Comment: If everything is the same between the 2016 and 2019, then that usually eliminates a lot of the issue.  Sometimes a proxy will cause issue.  Recently many server have switched authentication methods from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2.  OAUTH2 is preferred because is can run on Windows, MAC, and Linux.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I think so. I can connect to the OPC server via UaExpert and also when running the .net app exe file (start local from file)  but it is not possible on IIS. It must be something about permissions but I can't find where to change permissions. still trying...

Comment: There has always been issues with Net library and encryption.  Most were fixed when Microsoft switched in Net 4.7.1 to use operating system for TLS instead of Net.  So using versions of Net before 4.7.1 encryption may not work. OPC Foundataion 1.4.368.58 uses Net 4.6.2.  See following for more details : https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples#readme  Make sure you have all security updates for Win 2019.

Comment: There are different authentication methods : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/configure-authentication-methods